# List Php Sessions for a user and remotely log that session out

Tags: php

In php i create a session with the id of the user. So i do

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

So say for user 3. Is there a way i could list all sessions for user 3? Also remotely kill the session(logging them out). I want to give users something like gmail where they can view sessions for their account. I also want to allow them to remotely log out sessions out for their user account. Most of my site is done but this is something i am very unsure of. I am not even sure if Php has support for this. I want to do this to beef up security. So say someone went to school or somewhere and forgot to logout they could just remotely do it from another computer with their account. Also i plan to store their IP in the session, also last time. So it can also list IP address, Last time.  Have any clues on how to do this? Has anything like this been done with php sessions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set up a session-handler, who writes the session data into a database. Then you can analyze that table to find other session with the same id.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Thats the session-way. But I would suggest to implement this on your own, because the session-data is serialized, so you must read all sessions, deserialize it and search for the one key "id".

You can create a table with (lets say) session-id, user-id, ip and time. Every time a user logs in you put a record into that table and on every request you should update the time (its something like "last seen").
If you want to know if there are other users with one id, simply select over the user-id column. The "legal" user can be identified by the session-id.
Next, if you want "remote logout" a session you can add a column "force_logout" or something. Now on the next request (of the "illegal" user) you read this flag and kill the session, if its set.

Comment: Good idea. I get what you trying to say, I do a check on every page load if the user is ban and then i echo out a page saying they are ban and die if they are marked as banned. So if the session is "illegal", could use 0 for active, 1 for not. So if its 0, echo they have been logged out and then die. All handled in the global header file. How do i handle garbage collection. Also if the session timed out, could some get the same session id if they logged in again?

Comment: Also can i check if that session is still active when i while list out the MySql Results? Like if they logout, i could have it tell mysql. But what if they time out? Can i check if the session is still active?

Comment: You can read out the *gx_maxlifetime' ini setting and compare it with the value you store in the *time*-column

Answer (score 0):

You can keep session_id (*get it by session_id() function while user login*) in the data base and for remote session termination (by REST for example) by user id use next function:

```
public function drop_session($session_id) {
        if ($session_id) {
            session_id($session_id);
            //session_start();
            session_destroy();
            session_commit();
        }
    }
```